# textfield not getting resized when used with Tab()

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

When I am loading TabContent.fxml as root scene, and I am running the application, I see on maximizing the window, the textfield size is regrowing as expected, but when I am creating new tab with Tab() and loading TabContent.fxml, on maximising window textfield size not resizing and it is fixed.

LearnFXML.java

```
package learnfxml;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LearnFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="learnfxml.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="New">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Generic" />
                      <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemNewMSDE" onAction="#openNewMSDETab" text="MSDE">
                           <accelerator>
                              <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="N" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                           </accelerator>
                      </MenuItem>
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About MyHelloApp" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="640.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
package learnfxml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MenuItem menuItemNewMSDE;
    @FXML private TabPane tabPane ;
    final KeyCombination keyShiftTab = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.TAB, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {      
    }    

    public void openNewMSDETab() throws IOException
    {
        int numTabs = tabPane.getTabs().size();
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab "+(numTabs+1));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        tab.setContent((Node) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("TabContent.fxml")));

    }

    public void initialize(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

TabContent.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="429.0" prefWidth="694.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="39.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="584.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="39.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="71.0">
         <children>
            <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="641.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" text="URL" />
      <Button layoutX="628.0" layoutY="11.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="POST" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="7.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. The `VBox` does not grow the `TabPane` vertically. To fix this you need to set the `VBox.vgrow` property to `ALWAYS`

```xml
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="640.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS" />
```

2. You restrict your `AnchorPane` in `TabContent.fxml` to the preferred size (`USE_PREF_SIZE`). Set the max sizes to `MAX_VALUE` to allow the pane to grow:

```xml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="429.0" prefWidth="694.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one suggestion, the way I am using to define textfield is correct or there is better way to do that ?

Comment: I don't actually see you using it (except for adding it to the scene) One thing that strikes me as odd though is wrapping it in a `VBox` without adding any siblings. In a `StackPane` it wouldn't make a difference, if you added the `TextField` to the `AnchorPane` directly. Furthermore you'll very likely need to inject it to the controller at some point. Probably it would be preferable to use `HBox` instead of the `AnchorPane` since this way it's possible to deal with different sizes for the controls on different OS/javafx versions...

Comment: Thanks, I will be thankful if you can check and help with the below issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041207/tabpane-in-hbox-inside-anchorpane-not-resizing-on-maximising-window